# Custom VC Transition not Dismissing Properly

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to recreate the stock UIAlertAction in a VC with a custom transition. I currently have the presenting working perfectly(`backgroundView` fades in and the 'notification' VC slides from the bottom). The problem I am facing is when I dismiss the VC the `backgroundView` doesn't fade out. It's as if it's completely bypassing my animation block. Once `completeTransition` is called the `backgroundView` disappears completely. What is happening?

```
class AnimationController: NSObject {
 let backgroundView = UIView()
}

extension AnimationController:  UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
  func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

    guard let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to),
        let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) else {
            transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
        return
    }
    switch animationType {
    case .present:
        backgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: toViewController.view.frame.width, height: fromViewController.view.frame.height)
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4)
        backgroundView.alpha = 0
        containerView.addSubview(backgroundView)

        let viewToAnimate = toViewController.view!
        containerView.addSubview(viewToAnimate)

        toViewController.view.clipsToBounds = true

        viewToAnimate.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: viewToAnimate.frame.maxY, width: viewToAnimate.frame.width, height: viewToAnimate.frame.height)

        let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.80, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations:  {
            self.backgroundView.alpha = 1.0
            viewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -viewToAnimate.frame.height)
        }) { _ in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }
    case .dismiss:

        containerView.addSubview(fromViewController.view!)

        let testView = fromViewController.view!

        backgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: testView.frame.width, height: testView.frame.height)
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

        let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.80, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations:  {
            self.backgroundView.alpha = 0.0
            testView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: testView.frame.height)
            print("backgroundView Doesn't fade out")
        }) { _ in
            print("backgroundView disappears here")
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you registered the transition delegate in your new top VC?

Comment: @SanthoshSKashyap It calls the animateTransition func so I don't think that's an issue...

Comment: Would it help to see a working example? https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7

Comment: @matt Thanks for that, I'm trying to animate the view out as 2 separate elements (background +view). This example animates it as a single element...

Comment: Just a hunch, have you tried dispatching it on the main thread? Next thing to try is to use layer opacity instead of view alpha.

Comment: No it doesn’t. The dimming view background is animated separately.

Comment: @mink23 You should check `backgroundView.frame` is not zero, duration is greater than 0. After these checks, try to remove `containerView.addSubview(fromViewController.view!)` and not setting `backgroundView.frame` in `.dismiss` case.

Comment: @squall3d I tried layer opacity, no difference. For some reason I am not able to access the initially created backgroundView (which is created in the present case) when animateTransition Dismiss is called, how can I access it and change values in the dismiss?

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/DraggableViewController

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're dealing with two separate instances of your `AnimationController` and hence two separate instances of `backgroundView`. One instance is instantiated for presentation and the other is instantiated for dismissal. Notice in your `case .present:` block you are calling `containerView.addSubview(backgroundView)` but you don't do the same in the `case .dismiss:` block. As a result, the `backgroundView` instance in the `case .dismiss:` block isn't even part of the view hierarchy.

What you need to do is call `self.backgroundView.removeFromSuperview()` in your first animation completion block. Then in your `case .dismiss:` you need to call `containerView.addSubview(backgroundView)` once again.

Try this...

```
    switch animationType {
    case .present:

        // ...

        containerView.addSubview(backgroundView)

        // ...

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.80, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations:  {
            self.backgroundView.alpha = 1.0
            viewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -viewToAnimate.frame.height)
        }) { _ in
            self.backgroundView.removeFromSuperview()
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }
    case .dismiss:

        // ...

        containerView.addSubview(backgroundView)

        containerView.addSubview(fromViewController.view!)

        // ...

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.80, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations:  {
            self.backgroundView.alpha = 0.0
            testView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: testView.frame.height)
            print("backgroundView Doesn't fade out")
        }) { _ in
            print("backgroundView disappears here")
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to present like this

```
//where DevolucionVC is you ViewController 
    if let controller = DevolucionVC() as? DevolucionVC {
                if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
                    var currentController = rootViewController
                    while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
                        currentController = presentedController
                    }
                    currentController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
```

you can dismiss it later by simply use

```
 dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

for present replace this code

```
    backgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: toViewController.view.frame.width, height: fromViewController.view.frame.height)
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.4)
    backgroundView.alpha = 0
    containerView.addSubview(backgroundView)

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.type = CATransitionType.moveIn
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromTop
    containerView.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
```

For Dismiss Replace this code

```
  containerView.addSubview(fromViewController.view!)
  let transition = CATransition()
  transition.duration = 0.5
  transition.type = CATransitionType.fade
  containerView.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
  backgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: testView.frame.width, height: testView.frame.height)
  backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
  self.backgroundView.alpha = 0.0
```

Comment: I just added this code in, in present it doesn't fade backgroundView in at all. Am I missing something?